# When I use Link via importing from 'react-router-dom' nothing is showing in my page

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

This is my code. When I run it it does not show anything on the page and it did not show me any err either.

```tsx
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import '../App.css';

function Nav() {
   return (
     <nav className="nav">
        <h3>Logo</h3>
           <ul className="nav-links">
              <Link to="/"> <li>Home</li></Link>
              <Link to="/about"><li>About</li></Link>
              <Link to="/Shop"> <li>Shop</li></Link>
         
          </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

Comment: Are you saying that no links were rendered? We need more context.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Are you rendering routes for these links to link to?

Answer (score 0):

why you dont use NaveLink?
Try this,

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
import '../App.css';

function Nav() {
   return (
     <nav className="nav">
        <h3>Logo</h3>
           <ul className="nav-links">
          <NavLink exact to="/"><li>Home</li></NavLink>
          <NavLink exact to="/about"><li>About</li></NavLink>
          <NavLink exact to="/Shop"><li>Shop</li></NavLink> 
          </ul>
    </nav>
  );
}

export default Nav;
```

Comment: I did, still it did not work.